# Error While Installing cordova via node.js

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

while installing cordova through NPM i am getting these error.

> C:\Users\460862>npm install -g cordova
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
>   npm ERR! node v6.1.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
>
> npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\460862\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9188-001
>   278c9\registry.npmjs.org\bplist-parser-\bplist-parser-0.1.1.tgz
>   npm ERR! Expected: d60d5dcc20cba6dc7e1f299b35d3e1f95dafbae6
>   npm ERR! Actual:   b810dff385201a3be7e8c86bdf7c71072d9a0cc7
>   npm ERR! From:     http://registry.npmjs.org/bplist-parser/-/bplist-parser-0.1.1
>   .tgz
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\460862\npm-debug.log

Help me resolve.

Comment: try `npm cache clean cordova`

Comment: tried got the same

Comment: Node Version 6.1.0 and npm version 3.8.6

Comment: Thanku soo much.. will try that too also today.